# paper-tab size re-adjusted despite having scrollable = true

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to implement the scrollable feature for a series of paper-tab's in a Polymer project, like so:

```
<paper-tabs selected = "{{selectedtab}}" scrollable>
  <paper-tab>Page 0</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>Page 1</paper-tab>
  <paper-tab>Page 2</paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```

Despite having my code be the same for the [scrollable example in the official Polymer documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-tabs), it is not working for me. Here is what is happening:

1. When I copy-paste more paper-tab elements to test it out, it shrinks the size of all the paper-tabs to accommodate the new ones. The arrows that are supposed to appear at the left and right of the paper-tabs element do not appear.
2. When I enable the scrollable, the original three paper-tab's are shrunk, instead of covering the full width of the screen. I tried setting the width:170px for each of the paper-tab's, but it's not reproducing the effect before enabling scrollable.

What can I do to maintain the width of all the elements the same so that they cover the entire width of the screen? that is, how can I avoid the re-adjustment when adding in more paper-tab's?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be by [design](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/blob/master/paper-tabs.html#L252):

> If true, tabs are scrollable and the tab width is based on the label
>   width

The problem is that `scrollable` will change the styles of the `tabsContent` div and thus the tabs won't flex.
The current workaround is to measure if your tabs do fit in your available space and if not set the `scrollable` attribute.

You can also create an issue in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-tabs/issues).